# Who should call Dispose on IDisposable objects when passed into another object?

Tags: c#, .net, idisposable

Is there any guidance or best practices around who should call `Dispose()` on disposable objects when they have been passed into another object's methods or constuctor?

Here's a couple of examples as to what I mean.

IDisposable object is passed into a method (Should it dispose of it once its done?):

```
public void DoStuff(IDisposable disposableObj)
{
    // Do something with disposableObj
    CalculateSomething(disposableObj)

    disposableObj.Dispose();
}
```

IDisposable object is passed into a method and a reference is kept (Should it dispose of it when `MyClass` is disposed?):

```
public class MyClass : IDisposable
{
    private IDisposable _disposableObj = null;

    public void DoStuff(IDisposable disposableObj)
    {
        _disposableObj = disposableObj;
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        _disposableObj.Dispose();
    }
}
```

I'm currently thinking that in the first example the *caller* of `DoStuff()` should dispose of the object as it probably created the object. But in the second example it feels like `MyClass` should dispose of the object as it keeps a reference to it. The problem with this is that the calling class might not know `MyClass` has kept a reference and therefore might decide to dispose of the object before `MyClass` has finished using it.
Are there any standard rules for this sort of scenario? If there are, do they differ when the disposable object is being passed into a constructor?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

A general rule is that if you created (or acquired ownership of) the object then it is your responsibility to dispose it. This means that if you receive a disposable object as a parameter in a method or constructor you usually should not dispose it.

Note that some classes in the .NET framework *do* dispose objects that they received as parameters. For example disposing a `StreamReader` also disposes the underlying `Stream`.

Comment: That is what I first thought, but I had a look at the StreamWriter class that takes a Stream in its constructor and that disposes of the Stream in its Dispose method.

Comment: @Jon: Mark is right about ownership. Here however you enter the fine art of API design. Some places in the .NET framework the designers didn't follow this rule, because they thought it made the use of these types easier in common scenario's. For instance, now you can write: `new StreamReader(File.Open("log.txt"))` instead of having to wrap the `File.Open` in its own `using`. This design routes users to the ‘pit of success’. This design however is questionable IMO because users might not expect this behavior, which makes it harder to use in other scenario’s and it hurts the overall usability.

Comment: @Steven: A StreamReader has to provide a means by which a routine that finishes with a StreamReader can dispose of any wrapped objects without having to know what they are (since different derivatives of a StreamReader may wrap different objects).  The nice way to handle such issues would probably have been to pass a constructor parameter to the StreamReader indicating whether (1) the stream should take ownership of the object and dispose of it, or (2) the underlying object is expected to outlive the stream, and something else will dispose of it.

Comment: @supercat: Exactly. Taking ownership and disposing an object isn't a bad thing per se, but the API should at least give you the possibility to suppress the disposal, as you describe.

Comment: This seems like the obvious approach, with the exception of factories/builders (which should create something and do nothing else). The .Net framework has some notable exceptions (Streams, TextReader, TextWriter etc) referred to as "dispose ownership transfer" in the Special Cases documentation for rule CA2213 (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/code-quality/ca2213-disposable-fields-should-be-disposed?view=vs-2019) (more discussion: https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn-analyzers/issues/2413)

Comment: If you receive disposable A in constructor of class B, often it will be assigned to the private B class field. And class B should implement IDisposable and dispose object A. If disposable A object will be used also outside the class B mayby you should copy it before pass to constructor in factory method or factory class.

Answer (score 40):

> **P.S.:** I have posted a [new answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38173142/240733) (containing a simple set of rules who should call `Dispose`, and how to design an API that deals with `IDisposable` objects). While the present answer contains valuable ideas, I have come to believe that its main suggestion often won't work in practice: Hiding away `IDisposable` objects in "coarser-grained" objects often means that those need to become `IDisposable` themselves; so one ends up where one started, and the problem remains.

---

> *Is there any guidance or best practices around who should call `Dispose()` on disposable objects when they have been passed into another object's methods or constuctor?*

**Short answer:**

Yes, there is much advice on this topic, and the best that I know of is [Eric Evans](http://domaindrivendesign.org/about#eric)' concept of [Aggregates](http://domaindrivendesign.org/node/88) in [Domain-Driven Design](http://domaindrivendesign.org/books/evans_2003). (Simply put, the core idea as applied to `IDisposable` is this: Encapsulate the `IDisposable` in a coarser-grained component such that it is not seen by the outside and is never passed to the component consumer.)

Moreover, the idea that the creator of an `IDisposable` object should also be in charge of disposing it is too restrictive and often won't work in practice.

The rest of my answer goes into more detail on both points, in the same order. I'll finish off my answer with a few pointers to further material that is related to the same topic.

**Longer answer — What this question is all about in broader terms:**

Advice on this topic is usually not specific to `IDisposable`. Whenever people talk about object lifetimes and ownership, they are referring to the very same issue (but in more general terms).

Why does this topic hardly ever arise in the .NET ecosystem? Because .NET's runtime environment (the CLR) performs automatic garbage collection, which does all the work for you: If you no longer need an object, you can simply forget about it and the garbage collector will *eventually* reclaim its memory.

Why, then, does the question come up with `IDisposable` objects? Because `IDisposable` is all about the explicit, deterministic control of a (often sparse or expensive) resource's lifetime: `IDisposable` objects are supposed to be released as soon as they are no longer needed — and the garbage collector's indeterminate guarantee ("I'll *eventually* reclaim the *memory* used by you!") simply isn't good enough.

**Your question, re-phrased in the broader terms of object lifetime and ownership:**

> Which object *`O`* should be responsible for ending the lifetime of a (disposable) object *`D`*, which also gets passed to objects *`X,Y,Z`*?

Let's establish a few assumptions:

- Calling `D.Dispose()` for an `IDisposable` object *`D`* basically ends its lifetime.
- Logically, an object's lifetime can only be ended once. (Never mind for the moment that this stands in opposition to the `IDisposable` protocol, which explicitly permits multiple calls to `Dispose`.)
- Therefore, for the sake of simplicity, exactly one object *`O`* should be responsible for disposing *`D`*. Let's call *`O`* the owner.

Now we get to the core of the issue: Neither the C# language, nor VB.NET provide a mechanism for enforcing ownership relationships between objects. So this turns into a design issue: All objects *`O,X,Y,Z`* that receive a reference to another object *`D`* must follow and adhere to a convention that regulates exactly who has ownership over *`D`*.

**Simplify the problem with Aggregates!**

The single best advice that I have found on this topic comes from [Eric Evans](http://domaindrivendesign.org/about#eric)' 2004 book, [Domain-Driven Design](http://domaindrivendesign.org/books/evans_2003). Let me cite from the book:

> *Say you were deleting a Person object from a database. Along with the person go a name, birth date, and a job description. But what about the address? There could be other people at the same address. If you delete the address, those Person objects will have references to a deleted object. If you leave it, you accumulate junk addresses in the database. Automatic garbage collection could eliminate the junk addresses, but that techncal fix, even if available in your database system, ignores a basic modeling issue.* (p. 125)

See how this relates to your issue? The addresses from this example are the equivalent to your disposable objects, and the questions are the same: Who should delete them? Who "owns" them?

Evans goes on to suggest **[Aggregates](http://domaindrivendesign.org/node/88)** as a solution to this design problem. From the book again:

> *An Aggregate is a cluster of associated objects that we treat as a unit for the purpose of data changes. Each Aggregate has a root and a boundary. The boundary defines what is inside the Aggregate. The root is a single, specific Entity contained in the Aggregate. The root is the only member of the Aggregate that outside objects are allowed to hold references to, although objects within the boundary may hold references to each other.* (pp. 126-127)

The core message here is that you should restrict the passing-around of your `IDisposable` object to a strictly limited set ("aggregate") of other objects. Objects outside that aggregate boundary should never get a direct reference to your `IDisposable`. This greatly simplifies things, since you no longer need to worry whether the greatest part of all objects, namely those outside the aggregate, might `Dispose` your object. All you need to do is make sure that the objects *inside* the boundary all know who is responsible for disposing it. This should be an easy enough problem to solve, as you'd usually implement them together and take care to keep the aggregate boundaries reasonably "tight".

**What about the suggestion that the creator of an `IDisposable` object should also dispose it?**

This guideline sounds reasonable and there's an appealing symmetry to it, but just by itself, it often won't work in practice. Arguably it means the same as saying, "Never pass a reference to an `IDisposable` object to some other object", because as soon as you do that, you risk that the receiving object *assumes* its ownership and disposes it without your knowing.

Let's look at two prominent interface types from the .NET Base Class Library (BCL) that clearly violate this rule of thumb: `IEnumerable<T>` and `IObservable<T>`. Both are essentially factories that return `IDisposable` objects:

- `IEnumerator<T> IEnumerable<T>.GetEnumerator()`
  (Remember that `IEnumerator<T>` inherits from `IDisposable`.)
- `IDisposable IObservable<T>.Subscribe(IObserver<T> observer)`

In both cases, the *caller* is expected to dispose the returned object. Arguably, our guideline simply doesn't make sense in the case of object factories... unless, perhaps, we require that the *requester* (not its immediate *creator*) of the `IDisposable` releases it.

Incidentally, this example also demonstrates the limits of the aggregate solution outlined above: Both `IEnumerable<T>` and `IObservable<T>` are way too general in nature to ever be part of an aggregate. Aggregates are usually very domain-specific.

**Further resources and ideas:**

- In UML, "has a" relationships between objects can be modelled in two ways: As aggregation (empty diamond), or as composition (filled diamond). Composition differs from aggregation in that the contained/referred object's lifetime ends with that of the container/referrer. Your original question has implied aggregation ("transferable ownership"), while I've mostly steered towards solutions that use composition ("fixed ownership"). See the [Wikipedia article on "Object composition"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_composition#UML_notation).
- [Autofac](http://code.google.com/p/autofac) (a .NET [IoC](http://martinfowler.com/articles/injection.html) container) solves this problem in two ways: either by communicating, using a so-called [relationship type](http://nblumhardt.com/2010/01/the-relationship-zoo/), [`Owned<T>`](http://code.google.com/p/autofac/wiki/OwnedInstances), who acquires ownership over an `IDisposable`; or through the concept of units of work, called lifetime scopes in Autofac.
- Regarding the latter, Nicholas Blumhardt, the creator of Autofac, has written ["An Autofac Lifetime Primer"](http://nblumhardt.com/2011/01/an-autofac-lifetime-primer/), which includes a section "IDisposable and ownership". The whole article is an excellent treatise on ownership and lifetime issues in .NET. I recommend reading it, even to those not interested in Autofac.
- In C++, the [Resource Acquisition Is Initialization (RAII)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resource_Acquisition_Is_Initialization) idiom (in general) and [smart pointer types](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smart_pointer%23C.2B.2B_Smart_Pointers) (in particular) help the programmer get object lifetime and ownership issues right. Unfortunately, these are not transferrable to .NET, because .NET lacks C++'s elegant support for deterministic object destruction.
- See also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16629582/240733) to the question on Stack Overflow, ["How to account for disparate implementation needs?"](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16533985/240733), which (if I understand it correctly) follows a similar thought as my Aggregate-based answer: Building a coarse-grained component around the `IDisposable` such that it is completely contained (and hidden from the component consumer) within.

Comment: +1 great answer. I like the aggregates idea, good realworld example and pattern.

Comment: Nice answer.  A couple notes: (1) I would posit that the concept of "ownership" is important to almost all mutable objects, regardless of whether they hold resources.  I would posit that 99.44% of mutable objects should have a single owner object that regards the mutable object's state as its own.  Other objects which hold references to the mutable object should regard such references as encapsulating its identity, rather than its state. (2) The aggregates concept is powerful here, in that the it makes the identity of objects within the aggregate a local rather than global concept.

Comment: @supercat: Your 1st note has given me quite a bit of food for thought. Will answer it once I've had some time to think on it more deeply. I think we should get together for a (geek) beer some time! ;)

Comment: As you already stated, C++ destructors a.k.a deterministic object lifetime really rule.

Comment: Great question, but unfortunately most systems are not domain based. There are service based and we have some controllers, services, proccessors and repositories. So aggregates are not a good fit in those scenarios

Answer (score 16):

This is a follow-up to [my previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7944828/240733); see its initial remark to learn why I am posting another.

My previous answer got one thing right: **Each `IDisposable` should have an exclusive "owner" who will be responsible for `Dispose`-ing of it exactly once.** Managing `IDisposable` objects then becomes very comparable to managing memory in unmanaged code scenarios.

.NET's predecessor technology, the Component Object Model (COM), used the following [protocol for memory management](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686638.aspx) responsibilities between objects:

> - "In-parameters must be allocated and freed by the caller.
> - "Out-parameters must be allocated by the called; they are freed by the caller […].
> - "In-out-parameters are initially allocated by the caller, and then freed and reallocated by the one called, if necessary. As is true for out parameters, the caller is responsible for freeing the final returned value."

(There are additional rules for error cases; see the page linked to above for details.)

If we were to adapt these guidelines for `IDisposable`, we could lay down the following…

### Rules regarding `IDisposable` ownership:

1. When an `IDisposable` is passed into a method via a regular parameter, there is no transfer of ownership. The called method can use the `IDisposable`, but must not `Dispose` it (nor pass on ownership; see rule 4 below).
2. When an `IDisposable` is returned from a method via an `out` parameter or the return value, then ownership is transferred from the method to its caller. The caller will have to `Dispose` it (or pass on ownership over the `IDisposable` in the same way).
3. When an `IDisposable` is given to a method via a `ref` parameter, then ownership over it is transferred to that method. The method should copy the `IDisposable` into a local variable or object field and then set the `ref` parameter to `null`.

One possibly important rule follows from the above:

4. If you don't have ownership, you must not pass it on. That means, if you received an `IDisposable` object via a regular parameter, don't put the same object into a `ref IDisposable` parameter, nor expose it via a return value or `out` parameter.

### Example:

```
sealed class LineReader : IDisposable
{
    public static LineReader Create(Stream stream)
    {
        return new LineReader(stream, ownsStream: false);
    }

    public static LineReader Create<TStream>(ref TStream stream) where TStream : Stream
    {
        try     { return new LineReader(stream, ownsStream: true); }
        finally { stream = null;                                   }
    }

    private LineReader(Stream stream, bool ownsStream)
    {
        this.stream = stream;
        this.ownsStream = ownsStream;
    }

    private Stream stream; // note: must not be exposed via property, because of rule (2)
    private bool ownsStream;

    public void Dispose()
    {
        if (ownsStream)
        {
            stream?.Dispose();
        }
    }

    public bool TryReadLine(out string line)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException(); // read one text line from `stream` 
    }
}
```

This class has two static factory methods and thereby lets its client choose whether it wants to keep or pass on ownership:

- One accepts a `Stream` object via a regular parameter. This signals to the caller that ownership will not be taken over. Thus the caller needs to `Dispose`:

  ```
  using (var stream = File.OpenRead("Foo.txt"))
  using (var reader = LineReader.Create(stream))
  {
      string line;
      while (reader.TryReadLine(out line))
      {
          Console.WriteLine(line);
      }
  }
  ```
- One that accepts a `Stream` object via a `ref` parameter. This signals to the caller that ownership will be transferred, so the caller does not need to `Dispose`:

  ```
  var stream = File.OpenRead("Foo.txt");
  using (var reader = LineReader.Create(ref stream))
  {
      string line;
      while (reader.TryReadLine(out line))
      {
          Console.WriteLine(line);
      }
  }
  ```

  Interestingly, if `stream` were declared as a `using` variable: `using (var stream = …)`, compilation would fail because `using` variables cannot be passed as `ref` parameters, so the C# compiler helps enforce our rules in this specific case.

Finally, note that `File.OpenRead` is an example for a method that returns a `IDisposable` object (namely, a `Stream`) via the return value, so ownership over the returned stream is transferred to the caller.

### Disadvantage:

The main disadvantage to this pattern is that AFAIK, noone uses it (yet). So if you interact with any API that doesn't follow the above rules (for example, the .NET Framework Base Class Library) you still need to read the documentation to find out who has to call `Dispose` on `IDisposable` objects.

Comment: CLS compliance requires that overloaded function signatures differ by more than the ref-ness of their parameters; I would suggest that it would be cleaner to have a parameter (perhaps an `enum` or `bool`) which indicates whether a factory should acquire ownership.  Using an argument in that fashion will make it possible to wrap object creation without having to write two separate wrapper methods.

Comment: @supercat: Agreed that an additional `takeOwnership` parameter is enough (and also CLS-compliant). At the core of my answer lies the idea of passing a `IDisposable` as `ref` so that the caller's reference can be reset. I found this quite elegant and a novel take on the `IDisposable` pattern that I haven't seen discussed before. This pattern will however not work too well with just one constructor since `ref` parameters are invariant (if that is the right term). So yes, your suggestion is definitely the better and easier option if (a) CLS compliance is important, or (b) you want to type less.

Comment: Unfortunately, the root of the problem is the need to have one object be the owner; yet have no mechanism for declaring (and remembering, passing along) who owns the object. If there were an optional "IDisposable.Owner" field, there would be a way to "pass the baton". And a way to know "someone else already owns this". And a way to know "someone else now owns this, so I shouldn't dispose it". Would also make it easy to have "multiple owners" (the owner field would be a collection). When last owner says "I'm done", it immediately Disposes. "Reference counting" is the cheap version of this.

Comment: I came here because – coming from C++ – wondered if `IDisposable` has something similar going on as C++’s `unique_ptr`, which has a first-class way to transfer ownership. Unfortunaltely, using a `ref` parameter wasn’t possible for me, because my function being an iterator function cannot have `ref` parameters at all.

Answer (score 7):

In general, once you're dealing with a Disposable object, you're no longer in the ideal world of managed code where lifetime ownership is a moot point.  Resultantly, you need to consider what object logically "owns", or is responsible for the lifetime of, your disposable object.

Generally, in the case of a disposable object that is just passed into a method, I would say no, the method should not dispose the object because it's very rare for one object to assume ownership of another object and then be done with it in the same method.  The caller should be responsible for disposal in those cases.

There is no automatic answer that says "Yes, always dispose" or "No, never dispose" when talking about member data.  Rather, you need to think about the objects in each specific case and ask yourself, "Is this object responsible for the lifetime of the disposable object?"

The rule of thumb is that the object responsible for creating a disposable owns it, and thus is responsible for disposing it later.  This doesn't hold if there's an ownership transfer.  For example:

```
public class Foo
{
    public MyClass BuildClass()
    {
        var dispObj = new DisposableObj();
        var retVal = new MyClass(dispObj);
        return retVal;
    }
}
```

`Foo` is clearly responsible for creating `dispObj`, but it's passing the ownership to the instance of `MyClass`.

Comment: Ownership is only a moot point for objects that will never change during their lifetime or those which are unshared; but it's almost impossible to write correct code using shared objects if the state encapsulated therein can change but one doesn't have a clear idea of who owns it.

Comment: Yes, weak design is weak. Spinning state in shared, mutable objects is a recipe for confusion. A well-encapsulated object ought to properly isolate its internals such that its interface doesn't encourage users to break it.

Answer (score 2):

One thing I decided to do before I knew much about .NET programming, but it still seems a good idea, is have a constructor that accepts an `IDisposable` also accept a Boolean which says whether ownership of the object is going to be transferred as well.  For objects which can exist entirely within the scope of `using` statements, this generally won't be too important (since the outer object will be disposed within the scope of the Inner object's Using block, there's no need for the outer object to dispose the inner one; indeed, it may be necessary that it not do so).  Such semantics can become essential, however, when the outer object will be passed as an interface or base class to code which doesn't know of the inner object's existence.  In that case, the inner object is supposed to live until the outer object is destroyed, and thing that knows the inner object is supposed to die when the outer object does is the outer object itself, so the outer object has to be able to destroy the inner one.

Since then, I've had a couple of additional ideas, but haven't tried them.  I'd be curious what other people think:

1. A reference-counting wrapper for an `IDisposable` object.  I haven't really figured out the most natural pattern for doing this, but if an object uses reference counting with Interlocked increment/decrement, and if (1) all code that manipulates the object uses it correctly, and (2) no cyclic references are created using the object, I would expect that it should be possible to have a shared `IDisposable` object which gets destroyed when the last usage goes bye-bye.  Probably what should happen would be that the public class should be a wrapper for a private reference-counted class, and it should support a constructor or factory method which will create a new wrapper for the same base instance (bumping the instance's reference count by one).  Or, if the class needs to be cleaned up even when wrappers are abandoned, and if the class has some periodic polling routine, the class could keep a list of `WeakReference`s to its wrappers and check to ensure that at least some of them still exist.
2. Have the constructor for an `IDisposable` object accept a delegate which it will call the first time the object is disposed (an `IDisposable` object should use `Interlocked.Exchange` on the isDisposed flag to ensure it's disposed exactly once).  That delegate could then take care of disposing any nested objects (possibly with a check to see if anyone else still held them).

Does either of those seem like a good pattern?

Comment: I have recently implemented (1) in a project (by necessity). The disposable objects are wrappers around a native API that has a main "session" object, from which "connections" can be created. Unfortunately the connections die with the session when the session is closed, which was not the semantics I wanted the wrappers to have. So I split the session into a reference counted "core", and an IDisposable wrapper. That way the "connections" can reference and keep the "session core" alive, even if the "session" object is disposed.

Comment: Doing that also simplified my locking code. Whenever I need the "session core" I use a `using (var core = GetCore())` block. `GetCore` then creates a `SharedReference` helper object, that "owns" one "count" on the core object. If the core object has already been released, `GetCore` will throw an `ObjectDisposedException`. Otherwise it will return the `SharedReference` object, which again will make sure that the "core" object isn't released, even if the wrapper object is concurrently disposed on another thread.
And +1 for mentioning `Interlocked.Exchange` :)

Comment: Glad you found the answer helpful.  Your edits look good; in VB.Net (which I prefer over C#) the keyword is `Using`, but since people seem to prefer C# for some reason the lowercase form is fine.