# How to properly dispose objects: injected vs. owned

Tags: c#, .net

I have a question about disposing objects.

Consider this `IDisposable` class

```
public class MyClass : DisposableParentClass
{
    private MyProp _prop;        

    public MyClass(MyProp prop)
    {
        _prop = prop;
    }

    public MyClass()
    {            
        _prop = new MyProp();
    }

    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (disposing)
        {
            _prop.Dispose();
        }

        base.Dispose(disposing);
    }

}
```

On the first constructor, `MyProp` is injected. So `MyClass` is not the owner of the object. But on the second constructor, `MyProp` is created locally.
Should I always dispose `MyProp`, or should I check first if it is injected or not.

```
public class MyClass : DisposableParentClass
{
    private MyProp _prop;        
    private bool _myPropInjected = false;

    public MyClass(MyProp prop)
    {
        _prop = prop;
        _myPropInjected = true;
    }

    public MyClass()
    {            
        _prop = new MyProp();
    }

    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (disposing)
        {
            if (!_myPropInjected) { _prop.Dispose(); }
        }

        base.Dispose(disposing);
    }

}
```

Comment: I'd favour the second approach. Disposing objects that you haven't created could lead to all kind of nasty surprises later.

Comment: Sounds very much like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4085939/who-should-call-dispose-on-idisposable-objects-when-passed-into-another-object?rq=1

Comment: @DmitryBychenko Because this would be `true` when it was injected as well, he needs something else (like that bool value) telling the two situations apart.

Comment: @Dirk Do you have a better approach? Second approach is really verbose when you have a lot of injected objects

Comment: If you have a lot of injected objects that individually can be injected or created internally, then no, I don't have a better solution, but it also sounds like you're failing the single responsibility principle.

Comment: This looks like a very fragile design to me. In my opinion, you should have two classes, one that create its own dependency (and gets rid of it) and one that doesn't. That renders the question moot and significantly reduces the chance at subtle bugs. Not to mention it's much more obvious for someone else later, including the future you.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If your class should handle these two situations:

1. It is not the owner of the provided object, it should not dispose of it
2. It is the owner of the created object, it should dispose of it

Then yes, you need to have a mechanism that tells these two situations apart.

A common method (common to me anyway) is to use naming convention like this:

```
private MyProp _prop;        
private bool _ownsProp = false;
```

ie. reverse the meaning of your flags, but this is details, your solution is just fine, and yes, you need to have a solution like this.

---

If you have a ton of these fields, where each must have its own bool field to handle this, it might be worth creating a helper class, such as this [LINQPad](http://linqpad.net) program demonstrates:

```
void Main()
{
    Injectable i1 = new Injectable();
    Injectable i2 = new Injectable(new Injected("A"));
    Injectable i3 = new Injectable(new Injected("A"), new Injected("B"));

    Debug.WriteLine("dispose a and b");
    i1.Dispose();

    Debug.WriteLine("dispose b");
    i2.Dispose();

    Debug.WriteLine("no dispose");
    i3.Dispose();
}

public class Injected : IDisposable
{
    public Injected(string name) { Name = name; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public void Dispose() { Debug.WriteLine(Name + " disposed"); }
}

public class Injectable : IDisposable
{
    private Ownable<Injected> _A;
    private Ownable<Injected> _B;

    public Injectable(Injected a, Injected b)
    {
        _A = Ownable.NotOwned(a);
        _B = Ownable.NotOwned(b);
    }

    public Injectable(Injected a)
    {
        _A = Ownable.NotOwned(a);
        _B = Ownable.Owned(new Injected("B"));
    }

    public Injectable()
    {
        _A = Ownable.Owned(new Injected("A"));
        _B = Ownable.Owned(new Injected("B"));
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        _A.Dispose();
        _B.Dispose();
    }
}

public class Ownable<T> : IDisposable
    where T : class
{
    private readonly T _Instance;
    private readonly Action _CleanupAction;

    public Ownable(T instance, bool isOwned)
    {
        _Instance = instance;

        if (isOwned)
        {
            IDisposable disposable = instance as IDisposable;
            if (disposable == null)
                throw new NotSupportedException("Unable to clean up owned object, does not implement IDisposable");

            _CleanupAction = () => disposable.Dispose();
        }
    }

    public Ownable(T instance, Action cleanupAction)
    {
        _Instance = instance;
        _CleanupAction = cleanupAction;
    }

    public T Instance { get { return _Instance; } }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        if (_CleanupAction != null)
            _CleanupAction();
    }
}

public static class Ownable
{
    public static Ownable<T> Owned<T>(T instance)
        where T : class
    {
        return new Ownable<T>(instance, true);
    }

    public static Ownable<T> Owned<T>(T instance, Action cleanupAction)
        where T : class
    {
        return new Ownable<T>(instance, cleanupAction);
    }

    public static Ownable<T> NotOwned<T>(T instance)
        where T : class
    {
        return new Ownable<T>(instance, false);
    }
}
```

Comment: Note that my naming convention would use an uppercase first character, but I adopted your casing convention for this answer, the "OwnsX" convention is still what I would use however.

Comment: Is there a less verbose solution? Cause in my situation, i use a lot of injected properties. Especially for testing

Comment: But will they all be individually injected or owned? Meaning, let's say you have 3 such objects, will either *all* be injected, or *all* be created, or can you inject any combination of objects and create the rest internally? If the latter, then no, you need one such value per field, though you could of course wrap it up into a helper class. If the former types, then you need to distinguish between *all* injected or *all* created, which would only require one such value.

Comment: It's actually either injected or created internally. So you're right, i can use 1 variable for this. Why didn't i think of this before :) Thanks

Comment: The helper class looks like a good idea. It can avoid human error. i'm gonna try to implement it in my project. once again, thanks

Comment: I added some static helpers to make the calling code a bit easier to read.

Answer (score 0):

A different note can be made here either.

It depends on what is your `MyClass` is doing actually.

For example, if we are talking about a class that reads video stream from device, after applies some filters to it and writes data to a user specified file, where file writing is made by stream passed from the outside, say like this:

```
public class VideoProcessor : IDisposable {
    private FileStream _videoFile = null;
    private VideoProcessor() {}

    //user specified FileStream
    public VideoProcessor(FileStream fs) {_videoFile = fs;}

    public void Dispose() {
        _videoFile.Dispose(); //Dispose user passed FileStream
    }   
}
```

disposing passed stream object during dispose call, makes actually sence.

In other cases, yes, it's better to not destroy object, if you are not an owner of it. Leave it to the caller to decide when it is appropriate time to do that.